# Using gsub to separate a sting into cities and counties

Tags: r

I am trying to split a string into cities and countries but having difficulty when the city or country in question is more than one word (Eg, aix-en-provence or United States). The current code I am using a will work for most like Paris, France but not for ones similar to those above.

```
 locations
 paris_france
 miami_united states
 new york_united states
 aix-en-provence_france
 auckland_new_zealand

current code used
city = gsub("([A-z]+)_([A-z]+)", "\\1", locations)
country = gsub("([A-z]+)_([A-z]+)", "\\2", locations)
```

so now city will return paris and country will be france which is fine but for other stuff like auckland and zealand will be returned. Guessing its obviously a case of getting it to recognise more than one word before or after the '_'

Comment: `strsplit(locations, "_")`?

Comment: Use `strsplit` for this, `strsplit(locations, sep = "_")`. Or if you like tidyverse and this is in a data frame `your_data |> tidyr::separate(location, into = c("city", "country"), sep = "_")`

Comment: If you really want to use gsub: `city = gsub(".+_", "", locations)` and `country = gsub("_.+", "", locations)`

Comment: @r2evans Completely forgot about `strsplit`, is there any simple way of splitting them into cities and countries in the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `new_zealand`, we have to take a little extra caution.

## base R

```r
strcapture("^([^_]+)_(.*)$", locs$locations, proto = c(city="", country=""))
#              city       country
# 1           paris        france
# 2           miami united states
# 3        new york united states
# 4 aix-en-provence        france
# 5        auckland   new_zealand
```

## tidyr

```r
library(tidyr)
separate_wider_delim(locs, locations, delim = "_", names = c("city", "country"), too_many = "merge")
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   city            country      
#   <chr>           <chr>        
# 1 paris           france       
# 2 miami           united states
# 3 new york        united states
# 4 aix-en-provence france       
# 5 auckland        new_zealand
```

---

Data

```r
locs <- structure(list(locations = c("paris_france", "miami_united states", "new york_united states", "aix-en-provence_france", "auckland_new_zealand")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```